# Android: Detect When SD Card Mounted as Disk Drive to a Computer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sdcard

I am writing an application that needs to detect when the SD card is mounted as a disk drive to a computer via USB or when it has been manually removed. I tried using a broadcast receiver for this purpose, but the onReceive is not getting called. My code is as follows.

```
IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();
        //filter2.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        filter2.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
        filter2.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED);
        filter2.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
        filter2.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        registerReceiver(new CustomBroadcastReceiver(), filter2);
```

My broadcast receiver is as follows...

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public CustomBroadcastReceiver(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED)){
            HardwareManager.IS_MEDIA_MOUNTED = false;
        }else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            HardwareManager.IS_MEDIA_MOUNTED = true;
        }else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)){
            HardwareManager.IN_AIRPLANE_MODE = intent.getBooleanExtra("state", false);
        }
    }

}
```

The onReceive method does not fire when I connect as a disk drive via USB.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add the "file" scheme (addDataScheme("file")) in order for the IntentFilter to match the broadcast ACTION_MEDIA_* action intents.

The ACTION_MEDIA_* intents have the path to the mount point in Intent.mData field (see [Intent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)) but an IntentFilter with no schemes set will only match an intent if it includes no data (see [IntentFilter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addDataScheme(java.lang.String))).

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported at SDK level.

*Source: [Android: Detect USB flash drive plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088338/android-detect-usb-flash-drive-plugged-in)*

Comment: Would this be possible with the Android NDK ?

Comment: I don't know. Will inform you if I got any hint.

Comment: i think listening to the ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED will work for API version 8 and android.os.storage.StorageEventListener will work for later versions of the API.

Comment: Corrections, ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED did not fire either. I used the final answer posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb and used that function to check the SD card status periodically through a thread.

Comment: Heshan, thanks for the info and selecting my answer. :) Can you test the `Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED` on Android 2.2+ (2.3, 2.3.3, 3.x ...)?

Comment: My pleasure :) I can do that... but not right now since I am working towards meeting a deadline. However, I doubt it will since the API documentation explicitly states that it is depricated and that for versions beyond 2.2 (API version 8 and above), android.os.storage.StorageEventListener is available 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly the ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED does not work. I need to work on API version 8, hence any android.os.storage.StorageEventListener is not applicable.

I used the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb) to update a static variable in a thread. This can also be used to carry out a custom broadcast as well. The method is as follows...
*NOTE: HardwareManager is a user defined class

```
private static class SDCardMountStatusMonitor implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){
            try {
                HardwareManager.IS_MEDIA_MOUNTED = sdIsCardMounted(); //YOU CAN BROADCAST SOMETHING FROM HERE INSTEAD
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public static boolean sdIsCardMounted() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Then in another place, I create a thread out of this Runnable and start it.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new SDCardMountStatusMonitor());
t.start();
```